Clarification regarding the transformation law of the Christoffel symbols
I'm learning about general relativity from Sean M. Carroll's textbook. I recently encountered the transformation law for the Christoffel symbols, and I'm confused, as it seems like I'm seeing two different laws depending on the source.
According to sources like Wikipedia, the transformation law is
$$\Gamma^{\nu'}_{\mu'\lambda'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial x^{\lambda'}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda}+\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial^2x^\nu}{\partial x^{\mu'}\partial x^{\lambda'}}$$
This seems to be the most common law I see when looking into this, and it is the one I was able to derive using the fact that $\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda}=\frac{\partial\hat{e}_{(\lambda)}}{\partial x^\mu}\hat{\theta}^{(\nu)}$. However, Carroll's textbook presents a slightly different transformation law:
$$\Gamma^{\nu'}_{\mu'\lambda'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial x^{\lambda'}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda}+\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial x^{\lambda'}}\frac{\partial^2x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{\lambda}}$$
The difference is solely in the term that causes the Christoffel symbols to transfom non-tensorially. My question is whether one of these is incorrect for some reason, or if they are both somehow correct or equivalent. What am I missing? In spite of looking, I haven't found any clarification on this.

You will continue to find such inconsistencies in the formulas you see in different books and papers. Sometimes, there are errors. Sometimes, different notation conventions are being used. The only way I know how to resolve this is to do the calculation yourself (you might have to do it many times before you trust your own formula) using the definition of the Levi-Civita connection and the fact that $$ \nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j = \Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k. $$

One way to trust that the two non-tensorial terms are the same (without explicitly manipulating one into the other) is to 1) make sure they are talking about exactly the same $\Gamma$, and 2) make sure you trust both transformation law proofs. I assume Carroll has a proof for his transformation law, right?

Carroll takes a different approach to the Christoffel symbols than I did. Rather than starting by defining the symbols the way I did, he defines the covariant derivative, saying that the Christoffel symbols are an ingredient of this derivative for which we still need to determine a formula, then derives the transformation law of the Christoffel symbols that would be necessary to make the covariant derivative transform as a tensor. For some reason, these two approaches seem to yield different results, but they look very similar.
